# windows server 2003 sp2, not able to connect network drive over IP

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

One of our servers had a complete raid outtage and we had to reinstall it.
After the reinstallation with a Windows Server 2003 SP1 CD and the upgrade to SP2 afterwards I'm not
able to connect a shared network drive on the server over it's IP address. 
Yes, only, over it's ip... A connection over its hostname or fqdn is working.

I did not try to connect to the Windows Server prior the SP2 installation. The acutal windows version is: 
Version 5.2 (Build 3790.srv03_sp2_gdr.100216-1301 : Service Pack 2)

Here are the net use examples. The connections were made from a server in the same domain and ip subnet.

```
net use U: \\192.168.1.2\d$
System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found.

net use U: \\hostname\d$ 
The command completed successfully.

net use U: \\hostname.fqdn.com\d$
The command completed successfully.
```

If I try to connect to the server from a computer which is in another domain and ip subnet I get another error message (connection from client to server is possible):

```
net use U: \\192.168.1.2\d$
System error 59 has occurred. 
An unexpected network error occurred.

net use U: \\hostname\d$ 
System error 59 has occurred. 
An unexpected network error occurred.

net use U: \\hostname.fqdn.com\d$
System error 59 has occurred. 
An unexpected network error occurred.
```

The dns resolution works fine, and I've already rejoined the server into the domain.
Could it be any issue with netbios ? Or do you now a method to debug the network share connection
more detailed ?

The hardware looks OK. DELL OpenManage is installed and does not report any errors. The newest
drivers for the Intel NIC is installed.

Thank you very much for your help, I have never seen such an issue before and do not
know how to collect more information for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging this issue for nearly a week we've installed the newest NIC drivers. Unfortunately this didn't really help either so a Windows Repair from the Windows Server 2003 SP1 installation CD was executed and the Service Pack 2 installed again.

And suddenly it works ;-)

I'm pretty sure that some dll's were corrupted.